# Given $\phi ,\psi\in$ End($V$), show that $\phi \psi$ and $\psi \phi$ have the same eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given $\phi ,\psi\in$ End($V$), show that $\phi \psi$ and $\psi \phi$ have the same eigenvalues. (Hint: Consider the cases $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda \neq 0$ separately.)

I guess I'm getting confused on what $\phi \psi$ and $\psi \phi$ will look like.

Do I do something like: Let $\lambda_1$ be the eigenvalue of $\phi \psi$ then $\phi \psi (v) = \lambda_1 v$ and let $\lambda_2$ be the eigenvalue for $\psi \phi$ and then $\psi \phi(v) = \lambda_2 v$ and then try to solve to make them equal? How does one go about doing that?

Comment: Some assumptions?  $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, perhaps?

Comment: In general this is not true. If $V$ is the space of polynomials, $\phi$ formal differentiation, $\psi$ formal integration, then $\phi\psi$ is the identity wheras $\psi\phi$ has nontrivial kernel. - To give another hint for the $\lambda\ne 0$ part: $\phi\psi\,\phi v=\phi\,\psi\phi v$ (but to exploit that, $V$ must be finite-dimensional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension is finite here.

Suppose that $\phi(\psi(x))=0, x\neq 0$, then $\psi$ or $\phi$ is not bijective an has $0$ as eigenvalue. So $\psi\circ \phi$ is not bijective. the same argument shows that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $\psi\circ \phi$ implies that it is an eigenvalue of $\phi\circ \psi$.

Suppose that $\phi(\psi(x)) =cx, c\neq 0$, then $\psi(\phi(\psi(x))=c\psi(x)=(\psi\circ \phi)(\psi(x))$. This implies that $\psi(x)$ is an eigenvector of $\psi\circ \phi$ associated to $c$. Remark that $\psi(x)\neq 0$ since $\phi(\psi(x))=cx\neq 0$.